# Loading a new Silverlight application from isolated storage

Tags: silverlight

Is there any way i can load a silverlight application from isolated storage and replace the current application ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that instead of just redirecting to another application on another url?

Comment: well - we want to store the entire application within isolated storage and have a very very light launcher that checks for a newer version, else loads up from the isolated storage. this would be an ideal case for OOB, but we are placing our appliation within a larger portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, you cannot do this. You could however store a dll, read and load it via reflection **if** you are in a trusted out-of-the-browser application.
Anyway I don't believe this to be a very good practice, it's very likely there is a different better way to solve your particular problem.

Comment: Are you saying that we can load an assembly that's stored in the `IsolatedStorage` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace the currently running application from within Silverlight code.

However you could create a single application to act as a shell.  You could store assemblies or entire Xaps in isolated storage.  Using the `AssemblyPart` class allows you to load an assembly from this storage, create an instance of an entry type and execute an entry point method.

The big **caveat** would be that this "stored application" would have to be coded specifically to work within your shell.  You would need to provide your ways in particular to allow for "application" level state to be accessed and a means of loading content assets such as images.